# Unable to run VMware - Failed to build vmnet

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, vmware

I am unable to run vmware and below is the error log as to why.

Any idea, though and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

```
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=5707 version=10.0.1 build=build-1379776 option=Release
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.13.0-031300-generic Ubuntu 13.10
2014-02-03T16:32:00.903+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-02-03T16:32:00.903+08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.903+08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-02-03T16:32:00.903+08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.904+08:00| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-5707.log
2014-02-03T16:32:00.935+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.935+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2014-02-03T16:32:00.935+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-031300-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include".
2014-02-03T16:32:00.935+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:00.935+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:00.950+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:00.950+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.198+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.203+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.203+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.210+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.210+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.214+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.215+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.220+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.220+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.225+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.252+08:00| vthread-3| I120: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2014-02-03T16:32:01.273+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.273+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-031300-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.273+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.273+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:01.289+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.289+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:01.528+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include
2014-02-03T16:32:01.528+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include
2014-02-03T16:32:01.528+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.528+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:01.542+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.542+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:01.546+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2014-02-03T16:32:01.553+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Got gcc version "4.8".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.553+08:00| vthread-3| I120: GCC minor version 4 does not match Kernel GCC minor version 4.  But that is ok.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.553+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.562+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Got gcc version "4.8".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.563+08:00| vthread-3| I120: GCC minor version 4 does not match Kernel GCC minor version 4.  But that is ok.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.572+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.572+08:00| vthread-3| I120: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.573+08:00| vthread-3| I120: GCC minor version 4 does not match Kernel GCC minor version 4.  But that is ok.
2014-02-03T16:32:01.573+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.573+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:01.587+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:01.588+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:02.909+08:00| vthread-3| I120: GCC minor version 4 does not match Kernel GCC minor version 4.  But that is ok.
2014-02-03T16:32:02.910+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.910+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:02.929+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.929+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:02.929+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.974+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2014-02-03T16:32:02.974+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-031300-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.974+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.974+08:00| vthread-3| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2014-02-03T16:32:02.995+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-031300-generic".
2014-02-03T16:32:02.995+08:00| vthread-3| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-031300-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2014-02-03T16:32:03.237+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2014-02-03T16:32:03.245+08:00| vthread-3| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2014-02-03T16:32:06.212+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2014-02-03T16:32:06.241+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2014-02-03T16:32:06.370+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2014-02-03T16:32:06.370+08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j2 -C /tmp/modconfig-mjoI0c/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-031300-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2014-02-03T16:32:19.531+08:00| vthread-3| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: Just want to mentioned that this patch works for me on ubuntu 14.04 and VMWare Player 6.0.1 out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: The solution also applies to 'VNetFilterHookFn' type errors on 10.0.1 on 14.04

Comment: Just commenting as this is a top hit on google, but is well out of date, and the top answer doesn't work. To get ubuntu 15.04 and workstation 11.1.0 (and probably older) working just follow these instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up

Comment: "probably older" - does not work, I tried with ubuntu 15.04 and workstation 10.0.2 build 1744117 :(

Answer (score 30):

I was able to fix the issue for 3.13 kernel using [this solution](http://ping8888.com/2013/12/13/vmware-modules-kernel-3-13/).

Author advises to patch vmnet sources:

Create file `vmnet313.patch` in your home directory with the following content:

```
205a206
> #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
206a208,210
> #else
> VNetFilterHookFn(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops,        // IN:
> #endif
255c259,263
<    transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
---
>    #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
>       transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
>    #else
>       transmit = (ops->hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
>    #endif
```

Alternatively download [this patch](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3bkbAMu) to your home directory and rename it to `vmnet313.patch`. For example:

```
wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3bkbAMu" -O vmnet313.patch
```

Next, execute following commands:

```bsh
# Change directory into the vmware module source directory
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
# untar the vmnet modules
tar -xvf vmnet.tar
# run a the patch you should have just saved earlier
patch vmnet-only/filter.c < ~/vmnet313.patch
# re-tar the modules
tar -uvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
# delete the previous working directory
rm -r vmnet-only
# run the vmware module build program. (alternatively just run the GUI app)
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

The last command (or `vmplayer`) should now run successfully.

Comment: The patch listed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/414783/unable-to-run-vmware-failed-to-build-vmnet/491687#491687, with the updates for typos, worked for me.

Comment: Linux xxx-OptiPlex-7010 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux; vmware: VMware® Workstation 10.0.0 build-1295980. This patch is PASS.

Comment: The solution also applies to 'VNetFilterHookFn' type errors on 10.0.1 on 14.04

Comment: `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` says that the `--console` isn't supported for me. `Failed to parse options.
Unknown option --console`.  I just ran vmware to finish the build.

Comment: This one worked flawlessly for me. The first one wasn't allowing for the patch to work successfully. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Does this work for [VMware Workstation 6.5](http://askubuntu.com/q/573936/363039) as well? I am having [a similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/573936/363039) but I am unsure whether the above patch is for `vmplayer` only. Thanks +1.

Comment: (Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file vmnet-only/filter.c
Hunk #2 FAILED at 204.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** malformed patch at line 35:

Comment: VMware 15, I have a problem when executing patch file
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** malformed patch at line 35:

Answer (score 10):

Using this vmnet313.patch including a couple of typo corrections (see @nonsleepr's answer), resolved my issue with upgrading with the 9.0.2 to 9.02.4 upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit Desktop.

This snippet is the content of [pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3bkbAMu](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3bkbAMu); but with 2 corrected typos at the very end.

```
--- vmnet-only/filter.c 2013-10-18 23:11:55.000000000 +0400
+++ vmnet-only/filter.c 2013-12-03 04:16:31.751352170 +0400
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
 #include "compat_module.h"
 #include <linux/mutex.h>
 #include <linux/netdevice.h>
+#include <linux/version.h>
 #if COMPAT_LINUX_VERSION_CHECK_LT(3, 2, 0)
 #   include <linux/module.h>
 #else
@@ -203,7 +204,11 @@
 #endif

 static unsigned int
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
 VNetFilterHookFn(unsigned int hooknum,                 // IN:
+#else
+VNetFilterHookFn(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops,        // IN:
+#endif
 #ifdef VMW_NFHOOK_USES_SKB
                  struct sk_buff *skb,                  // IN:
 #else
@@ -252,7 +257,14 @@

    /* When the host transmits, hooknum is VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING. */
    /* When the host receives, hooknum is VMW_NF_INET_LOCAL_IN. */
-   transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
+
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 13, 0)
+    transmit = (hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
+#else
+    transmit = (ops->hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
+#endif
+    packetHeader = compat_skb_network_header(skb);
+    ip = (struct iphdr*)packetHeader;
```

Comment: This snippet above is the content of "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3bkbAMu" but with 2 corrected typos at the very end. Using this vmnet313.patch resolve my issue with upgrading to the 9.0.2 to 9.02.4 upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit Desktop

Comment: This one worked for me as well. I'll add a comment under the related post to point folks here.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This is my error: make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic'
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only'
Unable to install vmnet

Comment: I get "Hunk #3 succeeded at 257 with fuzz 2.", but then the errors still occur. Looks like something has changed since you posted this patch. I am using kernel 3.13.0-37-generic

Answer (score 5):

I've met exactly the same problem (Linux Mint 17, **kernel 3.17**)

The solution found is:

```
# - as root user
$ cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
$ tar -xvf vmnet.tar
# - edit the file vmnet-only/netif.c and replace the line that looks like
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
to
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, NET_NAME_UNKNOWN, VNetNetIfSetup);
$ tar -cvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only/
$ rm -rf vmnet-only/
```

Then run vmplayer again.

[source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/VMWare#On_3.17_kernel_vmnet_fails_to_build)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me in Ubuntu 15.04 kernel 3.19.0-15

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Ubuntu 15.04, kernel 3.19.0-20-generic

Comment: Doesn't work on linux mint

Answer (score 4):

VMware needs to build some modules because the installer doesn't always have the correct version for your system.

Install build-essential.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This will install a compiler and all other needs.
Reboot and try to launch vmware again, this should solve it.

Comment: for other seperate reasons. i had my ubuntu reinstalled along with vmware player but now everytime i had it run, my GNOME desktop would crash. any idea why and which log files should i produce here? thanks~

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade 12.04 Hardware Enablement Stack to the 14.04 version without fully upgrading the whole system, then the vmnet module can fail to compile for vmplayer 6.0.1.  My solution was to upgrade to the latest 6.0.3 vmplayer.  Had no problems after that.

Answer (score 1):

For me, these solutions did not work. I am using Ubuntu 14, so I went on a quest and found the solution [here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2014/02/install-vmware-player-601-in.html).

The commands are the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Under a 32-bit system, you can install VMware Player with the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/VMware && cd ~/VMware 
wget -c http://goo.gl/kkfRJg -O VMware-Player-i386.bundle.tar 
tar -xvf VMware-Player-i386.bundle.tar 
chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle  
sudo sh VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
mkdir ~/VMware && cd ~/VMware 
wget -c http://goo.gl/Uxia2s -O VMware-Player-x86_64.bundle.tar 
tar -xvf VMware-Player-x86_64.bundle.tar 
chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle 
sudo sh VMware-Player-6.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle
```

After the install, everything worked well and I was able to mount a Windows XP VM with minimal problems. I had to update a few more drivers, but it did without no problems. VMWare Player 6 seems to be the one that works best with my version of Ubuntu.

Comment: As for the linux-headers package. There is a metapackage "linux-headers-amd64" which will install the latest version, no need to manually specify a fixed kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

I updated kernel image to "linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic" for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP while running Ubuntu Precise 12.04 with "linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic"(...but did not upgrade Ubuntu !)

After which, while starting VMPlayer 6.0, one of the error-messages logged by VMPLayer displayed "Failed to build vmnet.Failed to execute the build command.", and VMPlayer failed to start.

I've rolled back kernel image by removing the updated one.

```
apt-get remove 3.13.0-43-generic
```

Also removed the updated linux-headers.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now, the kernel image is back to the previous one:

> cat /proc/version : Linux version 3.8.0-44-generic (buildd@tipua) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:01:04 UTC 2014

After which, VMPlayer 6.0 is back to normal, and now works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is replacing `/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar` with working one taken from `VMware-Player-7.1.bundle`. You don't even have to wait for installer to finish, just copy the file somewhere else and abort. Next run `VMware-Workstation10.bundle` (in my case) replace `vmnet.tar` and run your working Workstation

Answer (score 1):

My version of vmware did not include filter.c; I found that I needed to patch vmnet using the patch listed here:

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2531821

```
diff -ur vmnet-only.a/driver.c vmnet-only/driver.c
--- vmnet-only.a/driver.c    2014-11-20 20:13:56.000000000 -0500
+++ vmnet-only/driver.c    2015-02-09 15:40:10.916640592 -0500
@@ -265,10 +265,17 @@
 {
    int ret = -ENOTTY;

+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 19, 0)
    if (filp && filp->f_op && filp->f_op->ioctl == VNetFileOpIoctl) {
       ret = VNetFileOpIoctl(filp->f_dentry->d_inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
    }
    return ret;
+#else
+   if (filp && filp->f_op && filp->f_op->ioctl == VNetFileOpIoctl) {
+      ret = VNetFileOpIoctl(filp->f_path.dentry->d_inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
+   }
+   return ret;
+#endif
 }


@@ -1191,11 +1198,19 @@
    struct inode *inode = NULL;
    long err;

+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 19, 0)
    if (filp && filp->f_dentry) {
       inode = filp->f_dentry->d_inode;
    }
    err = VNetFileOpIoctl(inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
    return err;
+#else
+   if (filp && filp->f_path.dentry) {
+      inode = filp->f_path.dentry->d_inode;
+   }
+   err = VNetFileOpIoctl(inode, filp, iocmd, ioarg);
+   return err;
+#endif
 }
 #endif

diff -ur vmnet-only.a/userif.c vmnet-only/userif.c
--- vmnet-only.a/userif.c    2014-11-20 20:13:56.000000000 -0500
+++ vmnet-only/userif.c    2015-02-09 15:41:02.150847338 -0500
@@ -523,7 +523,13 @@
       .iov_base = buf,
       .iov_len  = len,
    };
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3, 19, 0)
    return skb_copy_datagram_iovec(skb, 0, &iov, len);
+#else
+   struct iov_iter to;
+   iov_iter_init(&to, READ, &iov, 1, len);
+   return skb_copy_datagram_iter(skb, 0, &to, len);
+#endif
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on lubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am using vmware-player-14.0.0-6661328.x86_64.bundle. After downloading and installing the vmplayer, when i lauch it trys building the modules but failed. 
To fix it You have to download the patches from this braunch: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tree/player-14.1.1 . do not download the master because:

> Branch "master" cannot be used to build modules, it contains only common
>   files so that changes in them can be merged into all other branches easily.
>   To get actual sources, checkout a "real" branch

after downloading, unpack and cd into the extracted dir and do

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now start vmplayer and it should work