# Errors compiling vmnet for VMWare Player, 3.13.0-27-generic

Tags: kernel, vmware-player

**Update:** This problem went away after rebooting in 3.13.0-29-generic.

---

I am trying to install and run VMWare Player on Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-27-generic.  I downloaded and executed the latest official bundle VMware-Player-6.0.2-1744117.x86_64.bundle .  But it's not able to build the "vmnet" kernel module required to run.

I have installed packages `linux-headers-3.13.0-27, linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic, linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic`.

I tried applying the patch described at the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/444375/285902 .  That might have improved things but didn't solve all the issues.

Each attempt creates a file `/tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-*.log`.  One possible issue repeated in those files looks like:

```
2014-06-01T10:41:33.896-05:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2014-06-01T10:41:33.896-05:00| vthread-3| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
```

but that might not be serious, since `/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h` does exist.  Otherwise, the only thing that stands out is the last two lines:

```
2014-06-01T10:41:34.570-05:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j6 -C /tmp/modconfig-vzryEa/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2014-06-01T10:41:36.174-05:00| vthread-3| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

A manual command `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` outputs this:

```
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/task.o
In file included from include/linux/rtc.h:28:0,
                 from include/linux/mc146818rtc.h:15,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:76:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1342:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmmon-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.o
In file included from include/linux/dmaengine.h:24:0,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:31,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:23:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
In file included from include/linux/pm_qos.h:10:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:28,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/driver.c:32:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
In file included from include/linux/pm_qos.h:10:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:28,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/hub.c:29:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
In file included from include/linux/pm_qos.h:10:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:28,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/bridge.c:29:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
In file included from include/linux/dmaengine.h:24:0,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:31,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/userif.c:27:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
In file included from include/linux/pm_qos.h:10:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:28,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/netif.c:29:
include/linux/device.h:601:6: error: unknown type name ‘dv_match_t’
      dv_match_t match, void *match_data);
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:213:1: error: conflicting types for ‘VNetFilterHookFn’
 VNetFilterHookFn(unsigned int hooknum,                 // IN:
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:64:18: note: previous declaration of ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ was here
 static nf_hookfn VNetFilterHookFn;
                  ^
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c: In function ‘VNetFilterHookFn’:
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:264:16: error: ‘ops’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    transmit = (ops->hooknum == VMW_NF_INET_POST_ROUTING);
                ^
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:264:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c: At top level:
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:64:18: warning: ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
 static nf_hookfn VNetFilterHookFn;
                  ^
/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.c:213:1: warning: ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 VNetFilterHookFn(unsigned int hooknum,                 // IN:
 ^
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/hub.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/filter.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic'
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-oZb2a1/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

A Google search for some of those compiler messages turns up absolutely nothing.

What could I try next?  I'm willing to switch kernel versions if it might help.

Comment: It would be better if you post your solution as an answer and accept it so others could benefit, rather than posting it to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a newer kernel version and reboot.

For me, the problem disappeared when using kernel 3.13.0-29-generic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions at [this link?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player)  There is a core set of utilities that is not loaded by default, but which are required.