# VMware Workstation is not working in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, vmware-workstation

I have installed VMware Workstation and when i try to open it the following error message is displayed:-

[image]

And when I click on the Install button another error is displayed:

[image]

I also viewed the log file but couldn't find anything helpful.

Here is the log file :
http://pastebin.com/3LZRcZ7b

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Failed to build vmnet" for kernel 3.19](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617704/failed-to-build-vmnet-for-kernel-3-19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the solution of the above problem:-

[3.19 kernels and up](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up)

Since 3.19 kernel the vmnet module will fail to build. Therefore we need to patch it .Commands are given below :-

```
curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
```

Extract the vmnet module sources:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
```

Apply the patch:

```
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
```

Recreate the archive:

```
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
```

Remove leftover:

```
rm -r *-only
```

Rebuild modules:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Now, VMware Workstation is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The first post is correct.
if you still need help then

Install VmWare 11 No Errors
Video How to
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfTCrWqQeLY

Step by Step Tutorial With Pics
http://kubuntu.info/install-vmware-11-no-errors/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.