# Cannot Get VMWare workstation to run in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, kernel, 15.04, vmware

Hi all Below is a link to the pastebin that contains the tail of the error log produced by VMware Workstation 11. Questions related to this topic are for Specific versions previous versions of linux. Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this?

The issue is related to The last line where it is unable to start VMNET. I have tried disconnecting from my VPN and ;launching VMware with no success.

http://pastebin.com/p0zVCLVi

Thanks!
PB

Comment: possible duplicate of [VMware Workstation is not working in Kubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632974/vmware-workstation-is-not-working-in-kubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the snippet from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414783/unable-to-run-vmware-failed-to-build-vmnet/491687#491687) and paste it into a file in your home directory named `vmnet313.patch`.

Run the following commands

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xvf vmnet.tar
patch vmnet-only/filter.c < ~/vmnet313.patch
tar -uvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

What is done in the code block above is untar the source of vmnet, patch the problematic code and then return the vmnet module back to it's original state with the added patch.

**Source**

[Unable to run VMware - Failed to build vmnet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414783/unable-to-run-vmware-failed-to-build-vmnet)

Comment: root@OBSIDIAN:/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source# patch vmnet-only/filter.c < /home/dj/vmnet313.patch
patching file vmnet-only/filter.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 27.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 203.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 252.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file vmnet-only/filter.c.rej @ step patch vmnet-only/filter.c < ~/vmnet313.patch

Comment: see if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/583091/423973) helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution is for kernel 3.19 .

Here is a link to the solution of the above problem:-

[3.19 kernels and up](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up)

Since 3.19 kernel the vmnet module will fail to build. Therefore we need to patch it .Commands are given below :-

```
curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
```

Extract the vmnet module sources:

if curl command is not found then run : `sudo apt-get install curl`

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
```

Apply the patch:

```
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
```

Recreate the archive:

```
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
```

Remove leftover:

```
rm -r *-only
```

Rebuild modules:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Now, VMware Workstation is running smoothly.