# VMWare player Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: kernel, vmware, patch

I have been working on this problem for a while now and can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I've installed VMWare Player 5.0.4 for Linux 64-bit on my machine running Ubuntu 15.10.  Installation was successful, but when I try to run it says it needs to compile and load modules into the running kernel.  That's fine, so I click install, and get an error saying:

> Unable to start services.  See log file xxx.log for details

I check the log, which says:

> Failed to build vmnet. Failed to execute the build command

Did some searching and apparently it is because of the kernel version so I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414783/unable-to-run-vmware-failed-to-build-vmnet) to patch vmnet sources.

After trying that, I get failure with the following output:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-aKDAPX/vmnet-only/netif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-aKDAPX/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-aKDAPX/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-aKDAPX/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-aKDAPX/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Not sure where this 'log' is that it wants me to look at...

Any help is appreciated, I really need to get this working.

Comment: Why not use KVM?

Comment: I was using KVM, but I am running a project where I need to ping, and for some reason it wouldn't work.  I could scp to and from the guest, as well as download files using wget, etc... but pinging would give me a "bad address" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMPlayer 5 is really, really old.  Current version is 12.  You will be well served by downloading the current version, do you need a link to the correct address.

Comment: I was told to use this version for a project, and I am guessing it is because it is free.  I'll try 12 out to see if it works any better.

Comment: The only problem with 12, is an environmental variable which needs to be set in the wrapper that starts VMPlayer - [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade/689135#689135) talks about that.  VMPlayer can be downloaded from [here](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0)